# Submit spark application with yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I write a shell script that calls spark-sumit to submit an application to yarn with `yarn cluster` mode.
When the application starts up, will the client process(process that submits application ) be terminated?

That is, when the application starts up and I shut down the machine on which client process runs, will the running application be unaffected and keep running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `--deploy-mode` is `cluster`, Driver will be running in yarn cluster & Spark job will be running even if client machine where job triggers goes down.

If `--deploy-mode` is `client`, Driver will be running in client machine where job triggers, Spark job will be killed if client machine  goes down.

`application started` client process will not be terminated both cases, It will simply keep on printing logs on console.

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename